# Custom regular expression for password with one special character

Tags: php, regex, passwords

So I need a regular expression that can provide the following rules

1. 8 character long minimum,
2. at least one UPPERCASE character
3. 1 special character

I have something like this right now:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{4,8}$
```

But I also need the special character, and I don't know how to do that, if anyone has a suggestion

Comment: You can use [`count_chars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) instead of regex matching

Comment: Yeah, but I will like to do this with regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the special characters you wish to allow. The match you have currently is matches between 4 and 8 characters, the one below minimum 8 maximum 20

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,20})
```